# Explanation needed in one step in solving an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, word-problem

Question is:

> At a swim meet, Janet Dives from a diving board that is $40$ feet high. Her position above water is represented by the equation $h(t) = -16t^2 + 24t + 40$, where $t$ represents time in seconds and $h(t)$ represents height in feet?

And this is how they solved it.
\begin{align*}
0 &= -16t^2 + 24t + 40\\
0 &= 2t^2 - 3t - 5\\
0 &= (2t - 5)(t + 1)\end{align*} I get that $0$ is plugged in, but how did they get from $16$ to $2$ in the next step?

Comment: Divide both sides of the equation $0 = -16t^2+24t+40$ by $-8$.

Comment: That can't be the actual question; it's not actually a question at all (doesn't have a who-what-when-where-how subject).

Answer (score 1):

Divide everything by $-8$. The equation $x=0$ is equivalent to $\frac{x}{-8}=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why to divide by -8? it doesn't say anything in the question?

Comment: It just helps to solve the equation... it's not necessary, but $0 = 2t^2 - 3t - 5$ is "easier" to handle (for human minds) usually than $0 = -16t^2 + 24t + 40$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, the following steps $$0=-16t^2+24t+40$$ 
Taking $-8$ common from RHS we get 
$$0=-8(2t^2-3t-5)$$ since, $-8\neq 0$ hence dividing by $-8$ both the sides, we get  $$\frac{0}{-8}=\frac{-8(2t^2-3t-5)}{-8}$$

$$0=2t^2-3t-5$$ $$0=\underbrace{2t^2-5t}+\underbrace{2t-5}$$
$$0=t(2t-5)+(2t-5)$$
$$0=(2t-5)(t+1)$$
That is the final result